# SVN merges massively changed code

Tags: svn, merge

I have a question where we have a project who's source code was originally written in Spanish. As more developers join the project, the original developer decides to change all the Spanish syntax to English.

The question is, we have divided the tasks to multiple developers and all of us will start implementing features based on the Spanish source code. We're afraid if the source code syntax changes to English, at the same time, we're modifying the code, will we have trouble to merge the features with all English syntax?

What will be the best approach to address this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Darcs can track changes like this.  It's still a good idea to get this over with before doing any more work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, best approach is to split the merges.  Have one merge that is *only* a translation exercise and one merge that changes the functionality.

Do not allow your developers to change code and language in one go because looking back at diffs when you're trying to track down where a bug was introduced will be a nightmare.

EDIT - Re-reading the question, it's not your team that doing the language change.  In which case can you get the original dev to branch the code and you work on a stable Spanish branch until he changes the API to English?

Answer (score 1):

If at all possibe, get the new Syntax first then start working.

Otherwise, the moment you start merging, you will hit compilation errors as types change names - you will not be able to tell which type you are supposed to be calling, as the name has changed.

However, if you can get the changes in increments, i.e. one function name at a time, you may be able to migrate as you go along. That is, they change a function name, and commit. You then pick this up and merge, making sure everything compiles. Repeat till done...